# image field getting null on edit form submit

Tags: symfony4

i have entity with three fields id,image,title.all are not null in database.image field is for storing file path.when i create new record it is working fine image is uploaded in public folder.but when edit that record image filed is getting null and This value should not be null message appear.image filed is not set and always getting null in form submit.

i follow symfony doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

entity field

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 */
private $image;
```

form type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
$options)
{

    $builder->add('title', TextType::class, [
        "label" => "Title"
    ])
        ->add('image', FileType::class, [
            'data_class' => null,
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array("label" => "Save"));

}
```

controller

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Gallery $gallery)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $file = new File($this->getParameter('gallery_directory') . '/' . 
$gallery->getImage());
    $gallery->setImage($file);
    $form = $this->createForm(GalleryType::class, $gallery);
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $file = $form->get('image')->getData();
        $fileName = $this->generateUniqueFileName() . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

        // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
        try {
            $file->move(
                $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
                $fileName
            );
        } catch (FileException $e) {
        }
        $gallery->setImage($fileName);

        $em->persist($gallery);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('Gallery/add.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'gallery' => $gallery,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `'data_class' => null,` in your form type?

Comment: if i remove  'data_class' => null from type i am getting LogicException.The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the example to upload a file in https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html to work either.
I modified your code to look more like some code that I got to work.  The code below has not been tested but should get you closer to working.

entity field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 */
private $image;

// Note there is no type hint on the return value.
// Sometimes it is a string, sometimes a UploadedFile.
// php bin/console make:entity adds a type hint which must be removed.
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function setImage($image): self
{
    $this->image = $image;
    return $this;
}
```

form type for creating entity:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
$options)
{
    $builder->add('title', TextType::class, [
        "label" => "Title"
    ])
        ->add('image', FileType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array("label" => "Save"));
}
```

GalleryEditType form type for editing entity:
(I do not know how to make a combined form for creating/editing.)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
$options)
{
    $builder->add('title', TextType::class, [
        "label" => "Title"
    ])
        ->add('image', FileType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array("label" => "Save"));
}
```

controller:
(I am less sure about this code, but you definitely need the UploadedFile type hint below.)

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Gallery $gallery)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(GalleryEditType::class, $gallery);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        // $file stores the uploaded image file.
        /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
        $file = $form->get('image')->getData();
        if ($file != null) {
            // The user selected a new image.
            $fileName = $this->generateUniqueFileName() . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

            // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
            try {
                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('brochures_directory'),
                    $fileName
                );
            } catch (FileException $e) {
            }
            // Update the image property to store the image file name instead of its contents.
            $gallery->setImage($fileName);
        }
        $em->persist($gallery);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('gallery_index', [
            'id' => $gallery->getId(),
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('Gallery/edit.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'gallery' => $gallery,
    ]);
}
```

Please post your updated code when you get it working.  Thanks!